# How to create string representations of objects in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, multiple-instances

I'm trying to create a game of Kings Cup (drinking game that involves cards) with Python. As it stands at the moment, when I print the deck and participants lists, it appears that the console is print out memory addresses. I would appreciate any help, pointers, tips, suggestions. Please and thank you.

```
import random

class Participant:
    def __init__(self, name, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender
        self.cards = []
    def drawCard(self):
        self.cards += deck.pop()
    def showCards(self):
        print(self.name) 
        print(self.cards) 


class Card:
    def __init__(self, value, suite):
        self.value = value
        self.suite = suite
    def getValue(self):
        return self.value
    def getSuite(self):
        return self.suite
    def __str__(self):
        return ("{0} of {1}".format(self.value, self.suite))

deck = []
participants = []

def shuffleDeck():
    for suite in ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]:
        for num in ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]:
        deck.append(Card(num, suite))
    random.shuffle(deck)
    return deck 


players = input("Enter the number of players: ")
numPlayers = int(players)
if numPlayers < 3:
    print(players)
    print("Not enough players.")
elif numPlayers > 12:
    print(players)
    print("That's too many players.")
else:
    for player in range(numPlayers):
        player += 1
        name = input("Player %s's Name: " %player) 
        gender = input("Player %s's Gender: " %player)
        participants.append(Participant(name, gender))

deck = shuffleDeck()

print(deck)
print(participants)
```

Comment: You just need to define a `__repr__` as well as a `__str__`. Or, alternatively, don’t try to print lists of Cards, print each Card individually, because lists always show the repr of their contents, not the str, because lists aren’t really meant for “human” (as opposed to programmer) consumption.

Comment: Typically, your repr should look like `Card("2", "Hearts")`. In other words, like a Python expression that would create an equal object if you pasted it into the interactive interpreter, because you normally only print the repr out for debugging purposes.

Comment: Your indentation is off in the append `shuffleDeck` function. The append method needs to be nested in the second loop.

Comment: Thanks guys. I was only printing out the entire deck to testing purposes. My code is still a work in progress. I appreciate your guys' help.

Comment: @nicholishen You're right. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a representation for each instance. For example:

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, value, suite):
        self.value = value
        self.suite = suite
    def getValue(self):
        return self.value
    def getSuite(self):
        return self.suite
    def __str__(self):
        return ("{0} of {1}".format(self.value, self.suite))
    def __repr__(self):
        return ("{0} of {1}".format(self.value, self.suite))
```

Then

```
>> a = [Card(3,'Diamonds'),Card(2,'Spades')]
>> print(a)
[3 of Diamonds, 2 of Spades]
```

That said, see @abarnerts comments about formatting repr

Answer (score 1):

Python stores information in memory with pointers. When you create a variable, you say: Hey python, remember that this variable points to this piece of memory.

When you print a string or a number, python will auto format it for you, but when more complex objects are involved, it doesn’t know what to do.

To inform python what to do, you need to create the magic function `__str__` (2 underscores on each sides) which you already did.

The problem is, when you print a list, you don’t print each individual objects, you print what the list **represents** of each objects. It’s more useful like that, because you’re not storing simple objects like strings or ints, but complex and defined *structures*.

To tell python what to *represent*, you need to create the magic function `__repr__`. I strongly suggest that you do not copy the `__str__` function. It would be preferred to print something like `Card(*value*, *suite*)`. In other words: your init function.

Gift code:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '{}({}, {})'.format(self.__name__, self.value, self.suite)
```

Comment: strings *are objects*. Classes are *always involved*.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t word it correctly, what I meant is: “but when non-*default* objects are involved, python doesn’t know what to do”. I’ll edit that.

Comment: I think the phrase is *user-defined* classes.

Comment: It also applies to non-user defined classes, but I guess this is what it concerns, so yeah.

Comment: Well, essentially, you are inheriting `object.__repr__` if you do t define your own (or inherit another)